# How to use GREP or AWK to extract only fields of a matching line

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I want to extract only the CVE-nnnn-nnnn numbers matching REGEX - `CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,19}` from a text file.  The presentation of the CVE is different in each line, due to the merging of data sets.

```
cat text.txt
Security updates available for Adobe Flash Player (CVE-2014-8439)
CVE-2016-4449: SUSE Linux Security Advisory
Security vulnerabilities fixed in Firefox 66:CVE-2019-9799
```

I can match the lines using `egrep 'CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,19}' test.txt`

How do I extract ONLY the CVE number to get the list using grep or AWK?

```
CVE-2014-8439
CVE-2016-4449
CVE-2019-9799
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some extra lines (multiple CVE, variable number of digits in last tuple):

```
$ cat test.txt
Security updates available for Adobe Flash Player (CVE-2014-8439)
CVE-2016-4449: SUSE Linux Security Advisory
Security vulnerabilities fixed in Firefox 66:CVE-2019-9799

CVE-7777-1234: SUSE fixed in Firefox 66:CVE-7777-567890
CVE-8888-14: SUSE fixed in Firefox 66:CVE-8888-090923487
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { regex="CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,19}" }
      { while (match($0,regex)) {
              print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
              $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
      }
' test.txt
```

This generates:

```
CVE-2014-8439
CVE-2016-4449
CVE-2019-9799
CVE-7777-1234
CVE-7777-567890
CVE-8888-090923487
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
cat file|grep -Po 'CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]+'
CVE-2014-8439
CVE-2016-4449
CVE-2019-9799
```

or:

```
grep -Po 'CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]+' file
```

grep's `-o` = only matched pattern, and `-P` is for perl-regex

Answer (score 0):

```
# grep -Eo 'CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,19}' test.txt
CVE-2014-8439
CVE-2016-4449
CVE-2019-9799
```